# Tomcat now throws javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unable to get RequestDispatcher for Context after update to 7.0.59

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cross-context

I'm running the stock Java and Tomcat from the Fedora 21 distro, which has been working fine with my apps until the Tomcat 7.0.59 update came down recently. Now setting crossContext="true" does not prevent a fatal exception being thrown, which is the exception one would normally see if one had set crossContext="false". Here's the Tomcat version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Server built:   Feb 14 2015 21:28:39 UTC
Server number:  7.0.59.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_40-b25
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

And here's the exception being thrown:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unable to get RequestDispatcher for
Context: "/" and URL: 
"/calendar.jsp?nid=0&pid=185&layoutpane_id=7&cid=276&accessuser=".
Verify values and/or enable cross context access.
```

Any ideas? There seems to have been work on cross-context request dispatching in recent Tomcat versions, but I can't find anything that addresses this specifically. Here's the full exception trace:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unable to get RequestDispatcher for Context: "/" 
and URL: "/calendar.jsp?nid=0&pid=185&layoutpane_id=7&cid=276&accessuser=".
Verify values and/or enable cross context access. 
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:278) 
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:161)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:3021) 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) 
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190) 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I will add that there's an update in the Changelog that says a warning will be thrown for an invalid cross-context URL, but it's a warning, not a fatal exception, and the URL will be automatically fixed (ending slashes, etc.). And it's not the exception being thrown here.

Comment: which version was it before the update?

Comment: Pre-upgrade: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Server built:   Jun 16 2014 08:38:46
Server number:  7.0.54.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_40-b25
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation ... I did a yum downgrade to this version and the crossContext exception vanished. So it's a change between 7.0.54 and 7.0.59.

Comment: I wonder, would it be [this change](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56677) then

Comment: Looks very suspicious, but Mark says it was fixed in 7.0.55 onwards. Maybe not, though. I'll see if I can get any action over on Apache bugzilla - thanks!

Comment: yes, I meant that the fix itself might have caused the problem you are seeing.